# Rails - How to properly escape values in a update_all query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, escaping, sql-injection

So I have an update_all query that looks like this:

```
Task.where(...).update_all('position = position - X, parent_id = Y')
```

I want to replace X and Y with integer values. And I'd like to do it safely: "the rails way".
Any idea of how I can achieve this ?

---

EDIT: There is no position variable in my rails controller. If X = 1, The final query should literally contain "position=position-1".

Also, The [update_all documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all) specifies that this method only takes one argument: A string, array, or hash representing the SET part of an SQL statement.

---

EDIT 2: Alright, I got it working by slightly tweaking Arup Rakshit solution. Here's the final working solution:

```
Task.update_all(['position = position - ?, parent_id = ?', X, Y])
```

Comment: suppose X= 2, Y = 3 then `Task.where(...).update_all('position = position - #{X}, parent_id = #{Y}')`

Comment: Updated.. Please try.. It will work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Write as :

```
Task.where(...)
    .update_all(['position = ?, parent_id = ?', position - X, Y])
```

Read [`update_all`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all).

> **conditions** - An SQL fragment like "administrator = 1" or [ "user_name = ?", username ]. See conditions in the intro for more info.

**Demo:**

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.0)
[1] pry(main)> Person.pluck(:name, :email)
   (0.4ms)  SELECT "people"."name", "people"."email" FROM "people"
=> [["xxxx", nil], ["xxxx", nil], ["xxxx", nil]]
[3] pry(main)> Person.where(email: nil).update_all ["name = ?, email = ?", "foo", "test@test.com"]
  SQL (0.7ms)  UPDATE "people" SET name = 'foo', email = 'test@test.com' WHERE "people"."email" IS NULL
=> 3
[4] pry(main)> Person.pluck(:name, :email)
   (0.3ms)  SELECT "people"."name", "people"."email" FROM "people"
=> [["foo", "test@test.com"], ["foo", "test@test.com"], ["foo", "test@test.com"]]
[5] pry(main)>
```

Comment: opps I guess I got late by a few seconds. :P

Comment: `Model.update_all("position = 'position - X', parent_id = 'Y' ")` what about this?

Comment: @Sontya I'm lazy to handle *SQL Injecttion*, so lets Rails to do this job internally. :-)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. But rails throws a wrong number of arguments error. As per documentation: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all the Updates attribute is the only argument, and is "A string, array, or hash representing the SET part of an SQL statement"

Comment: Also, I don't know if I made myself clear in the first place, but there is no position variable in my rails code. By saying position=position-1, I want the position column to decrement it's value by 1.

Comment: Alright it worked. I had to change it to match my requirements. I edited the original question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MonsieurNinja Very easy `Task.update_all(['position = ?, parent_id = ?', "position - #{X}", Y])` should do the work.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it this way:

```
Task.where(...).update_all("position = ?, parent_id = ?",position - X, Y )
```